# System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

Tags: vb.net, poo, variables

Estoy haciendo un programa de prueba en que hay un textbox en el que se insertan nombres, dichos nombres se deben ir guardando en un array y luego al pulsar otro botón que esos nombres pasen a un listbox.

Cuando ejecuto el programa e intento agregar nombres al array, VS me arroja el error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

Creo que el problema puede ser a que no estoy creando una nueva instancia del array Nombre. En c# sería algo como "string[] Nombres = New String[1000]", pero en VB no se como se hace, he buscado informaciones en internet y he probado en traducir de c# a VB y hasta el momento sin éxito. ¿Cual podría ser la solución?

```
 Public Class Form1
Dim Nombre As String()
Dim Counter As Integer = 0

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    Counter = Counter + 1
    Nombre(Counter) = textBox1.Text

End Sub

Private Sub button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button2.Click
    For Each A As Integer In Nombre
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Nombre(a))

    Next

End Sub
 End Class
```

Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para crear un vector de 1000 posiciones como explicabas, deberías hacer algo así:

```
Dim Nombre(1000) As String
Dim Counter As Integer = 0

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Counter = Counter + 1
    Nombre(Counter) = textBox1.Text
End Sub
```

De todas formas, te recomiendo utilizar listas para no tener el problema de los límites del array, o sea, algo así:

```
Dim Nombre As List(Of String)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Nombre.Add(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: Funcionó, gracias.